# Есть ли в c# простой алгоритм шифрования наподобии XOR?

Tags: c#, криптография

Есть ли в c# простой симметричный алгоритм шифрования наподобии XOR? Или лучше самому циклы городить? Есть целая библиотека System.Security.Criptography но там даже непонятно где искать. Нужно зашифровать текст симметричным ключем и расшифровать (куки регистрации).

У меня смешаная форма аутентификации, и заставить работать стандартную библиотеку не получается. Нужно шифровано передать логин (строка).

```
string user = "my_user";
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipial( new (GenericIdentify(user), new string[]{} );
```

Comment: А чем вам не нравится xor в цикле? Вы думаете, библиотека сделает это лучше, чем вы сами?

Comment: Т.е циклом будет проще?

Comment: Ну, две строчки кода плюс заголовок функции проще, чем искать библиотеку и подключать её? Мне кажется, да.

Comment: В System.Security.Criptography нету необходимого вам шифрования гаммированием. По причине того, что данный шифр тривиален. И, как написали выше, написать данную функцию дело пары минут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось зашифровать с подстановкой симметричного алгоритма. Без `Stream` получается гораздо короче:

```
public static string RC2Cript(string q, bool cript) {        
    byte[] s1 = (cript)?System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(q):Convert.FromBase64String(q);
    SymmetricAlgorithm cripto = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();
    cripto.Key = new byte[] { 0x10, 0x24,0x76,0x45, 0x84, 0x64, 0x25, 0x34};
    cripto.IV = new byte[] { 0x14, 0x24, 0x76, 0x48, 0x84, 0x64, 0x25, 0x34 };        
    s1 = ((ICryptoTransform)((cript) ? cripto.CreateEncryptor() : cripto.CreateDecryptor())).TransformFinalBlock(s1, 0, s1.Length);
    return (cript) ? Convert.ToBase64String(s1) : System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(s1).Trim();
   }
```

С `DESCryptoServiceProvider` тоже работает. Хоr пожалуй хорошо, но тут можно любой готовый подставить.

Answer (score 4):

Автор, как минимум передавать данные аутентификации на удалённую сторону - это нехорошо. Если знание логина не позволяет провести аутентификацию, то зачем его защищать? Если же позволяет, то это тот же самый пароль. И в этом случае правильнее передавать хэш от этих данных (н.п. SHA256) + соль для внесения энтропии.

В противном случае, ты либо используешь аппаратные средства для ускорения работы (н.п. интринсики процессора), либо самый

```
public void Xor(Byte[] data, Byte[] key)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
     data[i] ^= key[i % key.Length];
}
```

Единственное, что ты здесь можешь ускорить - обернуть в `unsafe`, взять указатель при помощи `fixed` и работать с голой памятью, обходя проверки выхода за границы массива, но в случае первого цикла компилятор сделает это сам. Возможно, ускорит обращение к ключу.

А в .NET действительно есть множество алгоритмов шифрования, в том числе симметричных. Например, старичок DES.

```
public static Byte[] DesEncrypt(UInt64 desKey, UInt64 desVector, Byte[] decryptedData)
{
    Byte[] key = BitConverter.GetBytes(desKey);
    Byte[] vector = BitConverter.GetBytes(desVector);

    using (DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        provider.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(decryptedData))
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(decryptedData.Length))
        using (ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateEncryptor(key, vector))
        using (CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(outputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            inputStream.CopyTo(encStream);
            encStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return outputStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}

public static Byte[] DesDecrypt(UInt64 desKey, UInt64 desVector, Byte[] encryptedData)
{
    Byte[] key = BitConverter.GetBytes(desKey);
    Byte[] vector = BitConverter.GetBytes(desVector);

    using (DESCryptoServiceProvider provider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        provider.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        using (MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData.Length))
        using (ICryptoTransform transform = provider.CreateDecryptor(key, vector))
        using (CryptoStream decStream = new CryptoStream(inputStream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            decStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
            return outputStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```