# ASP Net Скрыть ID пользователей

Tags: asp.net, безопасность, signalr

Пишу проект на asp net c использованием стандартной (встроенной) системы идентификации, регистрации, логина пользователей.
Т.е. в БД имеются стандартные таблицы.
Конкретно есть таблица AspNetUsers в которой хранятся сведения о зарегистрированных пользователях. Там есть поле ID.
Есть страница users.aspx куда нужно вывести всех зарегистрированных пользователей(например имя, телефон, mail) и чтобы "имя" например было ссылкой, при нажатии на которую открывалась страница user.aspx с подробными сведениями о пользователе (подробные сведения вытягиваются из связанной таблицы).
Проблема в том что нужно передать параметр на страницу user.aspx. Параметром выступает Id пользователя. Нужно это для того чтобы собственно вытащить из БД нужные данные.
Соответственно Id всех пользователей становятся всем видны, и на странице users.aspx т.к. там формируются ссылки вида

```
"a href='/user?id=da9d2146-9812-454f-9355-dd908dd77653' >  Иванов/a"
```

и на странице user.aspx в url-строке.

Как скрыть Id пользователей????
Подскажите плиз.

Есть так же например код который отправляет серверу данные о том что пользователь законнектился (signalR) и тут тоже проскальзывает Id:

```
      $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
         chat.server.connect('642519d1-e776-40fd-9ccc-fae520a18011');
         });
```

Или функция отправки сообщения (тоже signalR), где нужно указать какой пользователь и кому отправлено сообщение:

```
    chat.server.send_mes_private('642519d1-e776-40fd-9ccc-fae520a18011', 'dbc8016d-e735-4214-85f5-81c490f72017', $('#btn-input').val()));
```

Соответственно если туда вставить другие данные то можно отправить сообщение не от себя, а от другого пользователя.

В коде явным образом не прописывается ID, его туда сервер вставляет:

```
 chat.server.send_mes_private('<% Response.Write(User.Identity.GetUserId());%>', '<% Response.Write(Request.QueryString["id"]); %>', $('#btn-input').val().replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
            $('#btn-input').val('');
```

А в сформировавшейся странице уже видны Id...
Спасибо.

Comment: Вы используете готовый компонент, по описанию не совсем понятно какой...  Если этот компонент не поддерживает шифрование, то... варианта наверное 2. 1) Ищите другую библиотеку чата. 2) Запоминайте шифрованый токен пользователя в куки при регистрации, и при обработке запроса - или в aspx или в asax (в коде который затрагивает вашу страницу) проверяйте токен на валидность, и соответствует-ли `Request["id"]` (если он есть) тому который в token.

Comment: Да, вы всётаки попробуйте отправить сообщение от имени другого пользователя, сначала. asp хранит кучу данных, в том числе и asp-токен под которым зашёл пользователь. Возможно там уже этот вариант2 реализовали предусмотрев такую проблему, и он не даст это сделать, не смотря на извесный id.

Comment: Попробовал - отправляется...

Comment: Тогда защищайтесь токеном. Мне для генерации токена понадобилось [шифрование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/700652/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%bc-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b8-xor) потому что хоr не катит, но потом задача авторизации отпала и готового примера защиты нету.